# Base case condition in quick sort algorithm

Tags: recursion, quicksort

For the quick sort algorithm(recursive), every time when it calls itself, it have the condition if(p < r). Please correct me if I am wrong: as far as I know, for every recursive algorithm, it has a condition as the time when it entered the routine, and this condition is used to get the base case. But I still cannot understand how to correctly set and test this condition ?

```
void quickSort(int* arr, int p, int r)
{
    if(p < r)
    {
        int q = partition(arr,p,r);
        quickSort(arr,p,q-1);
        quickSort(arr,q+1,r);
    }
}
```

For my entire code, please refer to the following:

```
/*
filename   :  main.c
description:  quickSort algorithm
*/

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void exchange(int* val1, int* val2)
{
    int temp = *val1;
    *val1 = *val2;
    *val2 = temp;
}


int partition(int* arr, int p, int r)
{
     int x = arr[r];
     int j = p;
     int i = j-1;

     while(j<=r-1)
     {
        if(arr[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            // exchange arr[r] with arr[j]
            exchange(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
        j++;
     }
     exchange(&arr[i+1],&arr[r]);
     return i+1;
}

void quickSort(int* arr, int p, int r)
{
    if(p < r)
    {
        int q = partition(arr,p,r);
        quickSort(arr,p,q-1);
        quickSort(arr,q+1,r);
    }
}








// driver program to test the quick sort algorithm
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int arr1[] = {13,19,9,5,12,8,7,4,21,2,6,11};
    cout <<"The original array is: ";
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    quickSort(arr1,0,11);

    //print out the sorted array

    cout <<"The sorted array is: ";

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not quite clear, but I will try to answer.

Quicksort works by sorting smaller and smaller arrays. The base case is an array with less than 2 elements because no sorting would be required.

At each step it finds a *partition value*  and makes it true that all the values to the left of the partition value are smaller and all values to the right of the partition value are larger. In other words, it puts the partition value in the correct place. Then it recursively sorts the array to the left of the partition and the array to right of the partition.

The base case of quicksort is an array with one element because a one element array requires no sorting. In your code, p is the index of the first element and r is the index of the last element. The predicate p < r is only true for an array of at least size 2. In other words, if p >= r then you have an array of size 1 (or zero, or nonsense) and there is no work to do.